# another ring structure on the Ext groups

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $M,N$ be $R$-modules. We have the following product $Ext^1_R(M,N) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} Ext^1_R(M,N) \to Ext^4(M,N)$

Take an extension $0 \to N \to * \to M$, another extension $0 \to N \to ** \to M \to 0$, and take the long exact sequence of the exact sequence of change complexes one gets where the chain maps are the 0 maps, i.e. the exact sequence

$0 \to N \to * \to M \xrightarrow{0} N \to ** \to M \to 0$.  This is an element of $Ext^4(M,N)$.

Is this product nonzero or useful at all?

Comment: How is this an element of $\mathrm{Ext}^4$? (Can you give a reference?) Also, this seems to only define a product from $\mathrm{Ext}^1$ to $\mathrm{Ext}^4$ – how does this define a product on $\mathrm{Ext}$ (yet alone a ring structure)?

Comment: $Ext^n(A,B)$ is the group of exact sequences with $n+2$ modules starting with  $0$ and $B$ and ending with $A$ and $0$ modulo isomorphism.  For example $Ext^1(A,B)$ are the extensions of $A$ by $B$.  To answer your second question, one can take an element of $Ext^i(M,N)$, say $0 \to N \to X_1 \to...\to X_i \to M \to 0$ and an element of $Ext^j(M,N)$ say $0 \to N \to X_1 \to...\to X_j \to M \to$ and form the element of $Ext^{i+j+2}(M,N)$ given by $0 \to N \to X_1 \to...\to X_i \to M \xrightarrow{0} N \to X_1 \to...\to X_j \to M \to 0$.  Hence this gives $Ext$ the structure of a graded algebra.

Comment: For the equivalence of this definition of $Ext^i(M,N)$ and the one you are familiar with, take say $i=1$.  Given an extension $0 \to N \to * \to M \to 0$ , take the long exact sequence in the first variable $0 \to Hom(M,N) \to Hom(*,N) \to Hom(N,N) \xrightarrow{\delta} Ext^1(M,N) \to...$ .  Letting the extension map to $\delta(Id_N)$ gives a map from the set of extensions  of $M$ by $N$ to the ext group you are familiar with.